# How do I put an QImage with transparency onto the clipboard for another application to use?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QImage that I would like to put on the clipboard, which I can do just fine.  However the transparency is lost when that data is pasted into a non-Qt application.  The transparent part just comes out as black.  I tried saving the data as a transparent PNG but nothing is usable on the clipboard.

This is what I have so far:

```
QImage mergedImage = mergeSelectedItems(scene->items());

QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData();

QByteArray data;
QBuffer buffer(&data);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
mergedImage.save(&buffer, "PNG");
buffer.close();
mimeData->setData("image/png", data);

clipboard->setMimeData( mimeData );
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a complete, minimal example?  Also, which OS are you running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I replaced

> mimeData->setData("image/png", data);

with

> mimeData->setData("PNG", data);

It works in MS Office and Gimp, but not in `OpenOffice`.

Comment: I appreciate you do not have the rep to do so, but this is not an answer, it should be posted as a comment

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few (mime) types that work well with every application/OS combination
(e.g. Text and Bitmap)

EDIT: Which really means: To decide if this is a general issue or something to do with your code, you have to provide more info.